# Using BlueprintJS' Portal breaks context

Tags: blueprintjs

We use the blueprintjs library heavily, including the Dialogs. The problem happens when we use React-intl library to translate strings in our dialogs. The react-intl library passes some data through the react context object. https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/4c7a766ec59f3fdceb5f0079359ca3919a23c5e3/src/components/message.js#L59

That means, if we change the context, all our UI changes, except for Popover and Dialogs. I suspect this is because the context does not update. Any workarounds / thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide any more details? We are using `ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer` [here](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/62d574ceac17250aeaf2df4a1f14861dd0d964c8/packages/core/src/components/portal/portal.tsx#L52) with the intention of preserving React context.

Comment: Sadly I cannot provide a simple example. We've got a React / Relay application that uses BlueprintJS's components. I fixed the problem by forcefully rerouting to the current route, which seamed to fix the problem. Not sure where the problem stems from though.